# Spring cloud stream with kinesis: AmazonDynamoDBLockClient thows excpetions in loop

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kinesis

We have a quite simple spring-cloud-stream app that reads from a AWS-Kinesis queue. It has worked fro some time without problems. It has only a small workload.

Today we receive more than 100 exceptions per second. (That is more than we have users on this app, so it look like an endless retry-loop)

```
WARN --- [s-shard-locks-1] c.a.s.d.AmazonDynamoDBLockClient : 
    Could not acquire lock because of a client side failure in talking to DDB
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ProvisionedThroughputExceededException: 
    The level of configured provisioned throughput for the table was exceeded. Consider increasing your provisioning level with the UpdateTable API. (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ProvisionedThroughputExceededException
...
at org.springframework.integration.aws.lock.DynamoDbLockRegistry$DynamoDbLock.doLock(DynamoDbLockRegistry.java:504)
```

The code is quite simple:

```
    @StreamListener(Channels.OUR_CHANNEL)
fun consumeThing(Thing: MutableMap<Any, Any>) {
    log.info("thing received: {}.", thing)
    // some methods to write it to our own datbase
}
```

We have only a basic configuration:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      defaultBinder: kinesis
      bindings:
        thingsChannel:
          group: aGroup
          destination: aDestionation
```

In AWS-Console, we see a warning that in DynamoBD the SpringIntegrationLockRegistry exceeds the read capycity. We put it from 1 to 10, but still have the problem.

How can I configure spring-data-cloud and kinesis that it is more resilent, and don't retry it without some waiting time?

Answer (score 1):

Please, take a look into possible options for `LockRegistry`: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-docs/src/main/asciidoc/overview.adoc#lockregistry

It looks like the policy on the table in AWS Console has been changes. You might need to reconsider some timeouts and read-write capacities for that table or for the client I've mentioned.

You may read more about DynamoDB Lock Client more [here](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-lock-client), which is already out of Spring Cloud Stream control. BTW, this is the name for the project, not `data`...